# Mixins in Dart: How To Use Them

Tags: dart, mixins

So I'm trying to create a simple little program where I utilize mixins. I want to represent a bookstore and have two products (books, bags)..but I want the abstract class up top (Com) to define methods that can be applied to all products (objects) without changing the individual classes. However, I have no idea how to implement this. The method can be as simple as tracking if a certain book is in the bookstore.

Here is my current code:

```
abstract class Com {
not sure not sure
}


class Product extends Object with Com {
String name;
double price;
Product(this.name, this.price);
}

class Bag extends Product {
String typeofb;
Bag(name, price, this.typeofb) :super(name, price);
}

class Book extends Product {

String author;
String title;
Book(name, price, this.author, this.title):super(name, price);
}

void main() {
var b = new Book('Best Book Ever', 29.99,'Ed Baller & Eleanor Bigwig','Best 
Book Ever');

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

A Dart mixin is currently just a bag of members that you can copy on the top of another class definitions. 
It's similar to implementation inheritance (`extends`) except that you extend the superclass, but extend *with* the mixin. Since you can only have one super-class, mixins allows you a different (and much more restricted) way to share implementation that doesn't require the super-class to know about your methods.

What you describe here sounds like something the can just as well be handled using a common superclass. Just put the methods on `Product` and let `Bag` and `Book` both extend that class. If you don't have any subclass of `Product` which doesn't need the mixin methods, there is no reason to not include them in the `Product` class to begin with.

If you do want to use a mixin, you can write something like:

```
abstract class PriceMixin {
  String get sku;
  int get price => backend.lookupPriceBySku(sku);
}
abstract class Product {
  final String sku;
  Product(this.sku); 
}
class Book extends Product with PriceMixin {  
  final String title;
  Product(String sku, this.title) : super(sku);
}
class Bag extends Product with PriceMixin {
  final String brand;
  Product(String sku, this.brand) : super(sku);
}
class Brochure extends Product { // No PriceMixin since brochures are free.
  final String name;
  Brochure(String sku, this.name) : super(sku);
}
```